# Why doesn't work this circuit? I would like to sense the temperature raising

Tags: operational-amplifier, resistors

I would like the following:

Once the led gets active, stays active until I disconnect the power supply.

I tested it with this simple circuit, but it didn't work. When the temperature increased the NTC value decreased and the led went active, but when the temperature desreased the led went inactive. Why?

The NTC sense the temperature and if the temperature is too high the LED is go active and I would like to keep it active to see if the temperture was too high.
NTC is 10k.

[image]

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of the question you posted and deleted earlier.

Comment: Hint: look at figure 10 in the TI LM358 datasheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This circuit might not work, as the 358 has a maximum high level output voltage (VOH) which is about 2V below the positive rail.

Even when the output is high (3V), considering the diode drop, the maximum voltage you could bring to the non inverting input is 2.4V. That is, the non inverting input will not remain higher than the inverting input (which is 2.5V). In other words there could not be hysteresis.

Solutions:

- Use a rail to rail output op amp.
- In the resistor divider network for the non-inverting input: put a
  smaller value than 100k on the resistor connected to groun. Use 47k,
  for instance.
- Increase the supply voltage, for instance to 10. That way, Voh=8V,
  and 8-0.6 V > 4 V.

Comment: Or switch everything around and use the output low to drive the LED.

Comment: Nice one! Still I don't know what would happen if VOH is 2V below the rail and you put a red LED toward VCC. I guess that the tiny 50uA bias current (see schematics on datasheet) could be observable in dark. But I never tried.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, the output of that op-amp doesn't go anywhere near the 5V rail, so your circuit is a little flawed as is.

Personally I'd use a proper comparator for this circuit, but if you really must use that or a similar OP-AMP you would have more success using the op-amp in an active low output mode. You can do this simply by switching everything around as shown below.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBdoG3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The hysteresis is now on the reference line, where it should be. The circuit is still not completely latched ON though. The LED will still go out if the NTC resistance increases to the point where the negative pin voltage drops below the D2 ON level. However, I am assuming that input condition is unrealistic when given a 4.7K resistor value.

Note, I also upped the LED resistor value. 100R is rather small for that OP-AMP to drive.

I also added two capacitors.

\$C1\$ is used to force the circuit into a known state when the power comes on, that is, LED off. Your original circuit, had it worked, would be a "coin-toss" as to which state it started in on power up. \$C1\$ corrects this by ensuring the negative pin of the op-amp starts out at ground and decays up to the current sense value more slowly than the reference. (Assuming it had time to discharge since last power off.)

It also provides an added benefit of providing a little noise isolation.

\$C2\$ is of course simply decoupling.

Answer (score 0):

You need the output to stay above Vcc/2 + Vf of the diode to keep the op-amp output high because you have a fixed voltage of Vcc/2 on the inverting input.

That can be guaranteed at 25°C by loading the output with no less than 2K to ground (Vcc - 1.5V is guaranteed on the [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm358.pdf)). You are loading it with 100 ohms (in series with the LED) which is a very heavy load.

The 4.7K also loads the output. Without doing a lot of calculations, increasing the 100 ohms to 3.6K will certainly be safe. You should not call this too close because it is temperature sensitive so the guarantee at 25°C may not apply at your temperature extremes. It's possible to estimate the effect of temperature, but let's not get into that here.

[image]

If you don't like the brightness of the LED under those conditions, use the 3.6K to drive the base of an NPN transistor and put the LED between the collector and Vcc with an appropriate resistor in series.